# Get a value which is being inserted in DB via an HTTP request and later being used in another transaction

Tags: http, jmeter

```
JMeter Version: 2.9
```

**Test Scenario:**

To test purchase order creation process.

In the process, an HTTP request generates a `temp id` for the purchase being made and stores it into the DB. Later this `tempid` gets fethced from the DB and used in the purchase closure step.

Could anyone suggest how to get this `temp id` value from the DB and reuse the same later in the `JMeter test plan` in the purchase closure step.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is stored in the DB only and doesn't appear anywhere in DOM (page source) the only way to get it is using [JDBC Sampler](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65143-using-jdbc-sampler-in-jmeter-2-6) (or [JDBC Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor) wrapped in [Transaction Controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) if you don't want extra sampler in your results and extra time being tracked to HTTP Request).

You'll need to know database URL, credentials, etc. and have a proper JDBC driver somewhere in JMeter classpath - download the JDBC driver for your database and drop it to /lib folder of your JMeter installation.